# Swift Realm temporary storage

Tags: swift, realm

I'm searching the best solution to save an object during it's modification with Realm because if you put the app in background, the object's modified values are currently lost. I would like to save it without impacting the original object until user press save

I try two solution:

- duplicate the object (BaseObject, EditedObject) but this solution make a lot of code duplication.
- duplicate the object in the base storage, adding a bool property to know if it is a temporary object but this create issue for updating object.
- I've create different Realm Configurations but the data are available for both

Is there a way to have multiple version of a same storage? So I could have a RealmObject stored in a realm or tempRealm? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encapsulate my object in an array so I can keep track of different version of it.

If someone know how to create multiple storage of a same object type with Realm, please let me know

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to save the modified object as a dictionary in the UserDefaults with a specific key. You can check if there's a value for that key when the app comes back from the background and actually update the realm DB. Make sure to delete the data in the UserDefaults once the update is done.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: Hi tanks you, but as my object could grow up in volume, I think UserDefaults doesn't match here.